# !fmt for current line only

Tags: text-processing, vim, editors

When I want to format part of text with `fmt` in `vim` I usually select parts of interesting lines in Visual Mode, with: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Arrows</kbd>, and than type <kbd>!</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.

When there are couple of lines they are other ways of doing this:

```
:11,22!fmt
```

When text to be formatted is places between 11 and 22 line.

For one line I could write :

```
:22!fmt
```

But this is not comfortable to type new number, each time I change line.

Is there a way of doing this : `:22!fmt` without `22` but some mark, variable, that means *"current line"* ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.` means 'current line'. `.!fmt` does what you want